# Laravel "Malformed UTF-8 characters"

Tags: php, laravel, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou utilizando o Laravel na versão 5.4 (PHP 5.6) para desenvolver uma API.

Recentemente, quando a API foi publicada na Umbler (Linux), ao tentar acessar endpoints que retornam strings com caracteres especiais (mais especificamente ù, ã, í) e/ou UUIDs é lançada a seguinte exception

[image: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded]

A função do controller que está sendo chamada é a seguinte:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
         $response = $this->service->get($request->all());

         return response()->json([
             'message' => 'Success',
             'data' => $response['paginated']->getCollection(),
             'next_page' => $response['paginated']->nextPageUrl(),
             'prev_page' => $response['paginated']->previousPageUrl(),
             'current_page' => $response['paginated']->currentPage(),
             'page_count' => $response['paginated']->lastPage(),
         ]);
    }
```

Tentei utilizar accessors do laravel, nas entidades para devolver os dados das seguintes formas:

```
public function getIdAttribute($value) {
    return utf8_encode(Uuid::import($value)->string);
}

public function getValorAttribute($value) {
    return utf8_encode($value);
}
```

Mas o problema persiste.

Reparei que ao subir o Builtin Web Server (`php artisan serve`) em um servidor Windows o erro não ocorre, porém ao utilizar Apache ou Nginx, volta a acontecer.

**Obs**.: Neste mesmo servidor Windows, ao adicionar `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` as configurações do apache, o problema foi sanado, mas no Ubuntu não.

Alguém já teve esse tipo de problema e sabe resolver?

Comment: Kaio cade o método que gera essa informação, preciso ver ele!

Comment: Pronto, acabei de editar a pergunta! :)

Comment: o que retorna getCollection()?

Comment: A Collection da Entidade em questão, só que paginada. O problema ocorre em collections sem paginação também, desde que as mesmas tenham caracteres especiais.

Comment: Primeira coisa não precisa colocar utf8 nos metodos isso já tem problema, getCollection, tranforme para array pode ser isso.

Comment: o seu problema é de da base! primeiro não precisa conversões dentro do model dessa forma, em raros casos a gente faz isso, porque, realmente não precisa e acredito que seu problema é na hora de retornar esses dados paginados, se pode tirar tudo e colocar simples e testar!

Comment: Removi os accessors com utf8_encode(), foi só uma tentativa mesmo, não mantive no código

Comment: Passei $response->toArray() e obtive a mesma expcetion, os caracteres especiais são retornados da seguinte forma:
array('message' => 'Success', 'data' => array(array('id' => 'R9�Q�fDE�,'...

Comment: o erro é mais acima! não é no código ai! é na base de dados, e nas configurações de ambiente! como está configurado sua base de dados? e sua conexão.... como está configurado, veja, o erro é antes! não é ai

Comment: em config/database.php tenho as seguintes configurações de banco
 'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '----'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '----'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '----'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',
            'prefix' => '',
]

A collation foi copiada das propriedades do banco, que foi gerado via migration.

Comment: Então verifique no servidor as configurações se são iguais

Comment: Creio que no serviço de hosting que estou utilizando no momento eu não tenho acesso a configurações do servidor, mas eles dizem que lá o Apache e o PHP por padrão usam UTF-8.
Ao analisar o phpinfo() e comparar com o do meu Windows Server notei que na seção de Registered PHP Streams não há a opção 'sqlsrv', isso pode ter alguma influencia?

Comment: Kaio talvez não sei, acho que não, precisa ver como está configurado essa parte do banco. isso que você deve verificar

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, Virgílio! Quando eu conseguir resolver, posto aqui a resposta.